# ' assigned a value but never used ' stops Yarn from building code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, yarnpkg

[image]

I'm taking a look at https://github.com/intoli/remote-browser. I'm working in win10 with node 11.5.  I'm testing out the code by adding the following to my src/index.js

```
import Browser from './browser';
import ConnectionProxy from './connections/proxy';

export default Browser;
export { Browser };
export { ConnectionProxy };
export * from './errors';
export * from './launchers';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
process.stdout.write('hello:there ');
// const { Browser } = require('remote-browser');
// const browser = new Browser();
// browser.listen().then(port => console.log('Listening on port', port));
(async () => {
// Create and launch a new browser instance.
const browser = new Browser();
await browser.launch();

// Directly access the Web Extensions API from a remote client.
const tab = await browser.tabs.create({ url: 'https://intoli.com' });
const screenshot = await browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab();
})();
```

You can see that both tab and screenshot are never read in the screenshot, but this leads to :

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.17.3
$ Set NODE_ENV=production&&webpack --config webpack
clean-webpack-plugin: E:\ENVS\js\remote-browser\dist\extension has been removed.
Hash: 9cc6d50b90cbe6cd42f3f79034e4ca9daf45a4d0
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Child
    Hash: 9cc6d50b90cbe6cd42f3
    Time: 5548ms
                Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
        background.js     233 kB       0  [emitted]  background
            content.js    36.3 kB       1  [emitted]  content
            popup.js    30.9 kB       2  [emitted]  popup
    background.js.map     292 kB       0  [emitted]  background
        content.js.map    45.7 kB       1  [emitted]  content
        popup.js.map    39.2 kB       2  [emitted]  popup
        manifest.json    1.24 kB          [emitted]
            popup.html    1.22 kB          [emitted]
            popup.css  466 bytes          [emitted]

...................................
 ..................................

    ERROR in ./src/index.js

    E:\ENVS\js\remote-browser\src\index.js
    21:9  error  'tab' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
    22:9  error  'screenshot' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

    ✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: those are just linting errors, disable those lines and see what happens.  docs for longer-term solution:  https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#disallow-unused-variables-no-unused-vars

Answer (score 0):

The **actual error** is being produced in the **webpack** and it is **hidden**

they can be shown as mentioned [here](https://discourse.roots.io/t/yarn-build-error-exit-code-2/10225/2) :
It seems that, for some reason, errors are being hidden deliberately. If you change errors and errordetails to true you might find what is preventing webpack to run correctly.


try adding *errorDetails: true* to your stats object in the config